# Vector spaces over finite fields

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, finite-fields

There is an abelian group (w.r.t. addition)
$$V=F^n$$
where F is a finite field with q elements.

How do we prove the closure property of the scalar multiplication of an element from $F$ and an element from $V$?

I tried looking for ways to prove this but the sources I got didn't give convincing explanations or simply assumed the scalar multiple belonged to $V$.

Comment: You need to define the scalar multiplication first. If $F$ is a field, and $V=F\times\cdots\times F$, then you *usually* define scalar mutliplication by $\alpha(a_1,\ldots,a_n) = (\alpha a_1,\ldots,\alpha a_n)$. This is an element of $V$ because $\alpha a_i$ is a product of elements in $F$, and hence lies in $F$.

Comment: The proof goes the same way over the field of real numbers and over a finite field. Do you remember how this was done in linear algebra? Presumably reals were used back then.